# d3.js Sankey diagram: rectangles fill color

Tags: d3.js, sankey-diagram

So I am playing around with the d3.js Sankey diagram.

[image]

In [this example](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/sankey) (pictured above) color is defined using

```
var color = d3.scale.category20();
```

For each node there is a rectangle, and that rectangle is filled by altering the style:

```
.style("fill", function(d) {
    return d.color = color(d.name.replace(/ .*/, ""));
})
```

I'm looking for suggestions on using custom colors. If I wanted to use only say 6 colors, but have the node rectangle colors chosen based on a value in the .json file.

For example, lets say I wanted to show a snakey chart of teams in the NFL. The colours each represent which division the teams play in. So if they move to a different division, the color changes. And the nodes are created for every season. Something along those lines.

So is it possible to run the

```
node.append("rect")
    .attr("height", function(d) { return d.dy; })
    .attr("width", sankey.nodeWidth())
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return d.color = color(d.name.replace(/ .*/, ""));
    })
    .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return d3.rgb(d.color).darker(2);
    })
   .append("title")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name + "\n" + format(d.value); });
```

with the color based on a value in the json file? I am thinking just an if statement, but is there an easier way? Could I just include the hex color code in the json?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you want to include the colour in the JSON in this case. You can include it in any way that the browser recognises, e.g. as a name ("white") or hex ("#fff"). See the [SVG spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#DataTypeColor) for a full list of supported colour specifications.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was thinking. Based on what I am doing, this will work perfectly.

.style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; })

is now pulling in a color from the .json file associated with each node.

Answer (score 26):

Alternatively, you could map the colors to the division explicitly with a d3 ordinal scale as mentioned in the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales). See Colorbrewer at the bottom.

```
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["foo", "bar", "baz"])
    .range(["#fff","#000","#333"]);
```

and then

```
.attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.division); });
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I got it to work, but based on what I am doing, pulling colors from Json is easier. But this is going to be very, very helpful in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);` with:

```
const color = d3.scaleOrdinal() 
.domain(["Crude oil","Natural gas",...])
.range(["#FD3E35","#FFCB06",...]);
```

And stay with:

```
.style('fill', (d,i) => {
  d.color = color(d.name.replace(/ .*/, ''));
  return d.color;})
```